# Basic question to formatting custom error Messages

Tags: java, error-handling, custom-error-handling

i needed some help understanding the best practice for this scenario.

I have a custom exception class I created that has 3 child classes.I was overriding the message to fit my need .
Now the child classes also need to have a custom message. Can I somehow find a way to leverage using the parent class but with a different format ?

Parent Exception Class

```
public class customException extends RuntimeException {

String myFormat = " Custom Exception message here , %s, %s";

private String A;

public customException(String A, String message){
this.A= A;
super(message);
}

@Override
public String getMessage() {
return String.Format(myFormat, A, super.getMessage());
}
```

Child Exception class example

```
public class childException extends customException {

String myFormat = " ChildException message here , %s, %s";

public customException(String A, String message){
super(A, message);
}

@Override
public String getMessage() {
return super.getMessage();    // find a way to format using the ChildClass myFormat? 
    }
```

EDIT :

The workaround i had currently looked something like this.

Child Exception class example

```
public class childException extends customException {

String myFormat = " ChildException message here , %s, %s";

private String A;

public customException(String A, String message){
super(message);  // have another constructor in the Parent exception class
this.A=A;
} 

@Override
public String getMessage() {
return String.Format(myFormat, A, super.getMessage()); 
    }
```

And to avoid the super.getMessage() above, to print the format of the parent exception as well I was checking on the getMessage() method in the super class to see if the class is an instance of the child class. Not a suitable solution.

```
@Override
public String getMessage() {
if( this instanceOf childException)
return super.getMessage();
else
return String.Format(myFormat, A, super.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you change the return super.getMessage() line in childException class.

Instead of:

```
@Override
public String getMessage() {
    return   super.getMessage();    // find a way to format using the ChildClass myFormat? 
}
```

Try:

```
@Override
public String getMessage() {
  this.myFormat = this.myFormat.append("hello");
  return this.myFormat; // find a way to format using the ChildClass myFormat? 
}
```

Comment: Hi Ahmet , thanks for getting back .  I wanted to fill the Format based on the variables, String myFormat = " ChildException message here , %s, %s".  How do I fill them in . Sorry if I am missing out on something.

Comment: What do you want to print inside of those %s expressions? You could create a new method called buildMyFinalFormatSTring() in the type of String. Then in getmessage() method in the childexception class simple call return buildMyFinalFormatString() expression. 

As far as I understood, you want to change the value of this string variable called myFormat. To do this you have two options: either you do it in some method, or you do it in the constructor of  childException class. please bear in mind that this constructor in childexception class should be without any parameters

Comment: Sorry Ahmet looks like my question isn't clear. So for now, the getMessage of any child class would return that looks something like this: Custom Exception message here ...      What I wanted was to find a way to use the myFormat of the child class instead so it can return what i except in this case: ChildException message here ...

Comment: No problem, I would like to help you! What I don't get from your problem is that, you want your childException class to return a specific exception message. And you say that the message from parent exception class is returned instead. This is expected, as you say return super.getMessage(). This causes parent class message to be called. As an example, you can write return "HEllo" then hello will be printed from this method. I just triedyour code on my ide and when i return "hello"; in the child class, i see the message of hello. this basically means u re using the parent classes value otherwis

Comment: thanks Ahmet , i do understand that part that the current code will return the parent exception as designed. What I am trying to do is find a way to format based on the child class. I wouldn't be able to do something like this  "String.Format(myFormat, A, super.getMessage());"  in the child class getMessage as the variables get initialized in the parent class. I am adding a work around i have but i know is not suitable.